# What to call the approach of one who creates a lot of new words/phrases when translating?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

So this guy has his own approach in translation. He creates a lot of new words and phrases when translating a text because there is simply not enough or right words in the language he is translating to. Thus, in a sense he is creating a new language, which vastly differs from the language he is translating to.

What is such an approach in translation called? Is there any special word for it? Can it be called language-creating approach/language-building approach? Any suggestion?

Comment: The creations of say Stanley Unwin were normally not accepted as being words, but as nonsense. These were very funny in context, but do not belong on a website dedicated to English usage any more than non-standard song lyrics.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What exactly are you saying here?

Comment: So this guy doesn't create a lot of new words. He may come up with non-words or candidate words. Individuals don't have the power of conferring wordness.

Comment: So? Such non-words might get popular and even enter dictionaries. Anyway, my question is about how to call such act of creating words/non-words. You should explain your downvote, or the relevant approach.

Comment: I'll remove the down-vote when you change 'He creates a lot of new words' to 'He invents new candidate words'. / Such an approach in translation is usually called 'mistranslation'; the correct approach is to import the foreign term and explain its usage at length..

Comment: What is the significant difference in meaning between "create new words" and "invent new candidate words"? What does "candidate word" mean in this context? I think you've realised that the question is after all serious and on-topic.

Comment: @Sasan However, you're not doing yourself a favour by saying this translator is creating a new language. If that were the case, he or she would be out of a job pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**Neologism** or **neology** would fit. Both are defined by the Oxford English Dictionary as:

> The coining or use of new words or phrases

A relevant example here would be:

> You could take the time-honored neologism approach, stringing together sounds to create a new namelike creation (think Lando Calrissian).
>   <sub>[Naming the Future](http://www.babynamewizard.com/archives/2007/9/naming-the-future?page=5)</sub>

Comment: A candidate word doesn't automatically become part of the English lexicon. DIY attempts are not neologisms.

Answer (score 0):

I simply call it Hemingwaying. Hemingway was known for inventing words and phrases in his writings, so I like to use his name when acknowledging language editors.

If you would like an opinion on your choices--and a less abstract term--I like 'dialect creation approach'. Because if it's understandable within the language, but it's also very different making, it becomes a new dialect rather than a new language.

Comment: what would be your suggestion if the created words are not actually understandable by the usual readers؟

Comment: Please add references. Answers without references come across as no more than personal opinion or even error, and may be so. The 'U' in ELU stands for usage, and non-standard suggestions or DIY candidate words are inappropriate here.